# Can a sequence be undefined at a point?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A sequence which is a mapping from $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$.

For example can the sequence $\{a_n\} = 1/(3-n)$.
This would be undefined at $3$.
Is it a sequence?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 8):

If you define a sequence as a mapping $f$ from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$, then no, a sequence cannot be undefined at a point $x$, since if $f(x)$ was not defined, then $f$ isn't a mapping.

Comment: +1 for "just the facts", which is about all one can do unless the OP provides more information or context for the question. I was trying to write a comment about how $\frac{1}{3-n}$ certainly defines a sequence if we begin with $n=4$ or later, and how the same *infinite list of numbers* can have different functions showing they're sequences, then started to trip over too many things, after which I pretty much decided to give it a pass, and then your answer showed up.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a sequence of real numbers, then go ahead and start noting the first few terms. In your case it will be:

$\frac{1}{2}, 1, \infty,-1, \frac{-1}{2},...$

Is that really a sequence of real numbers? I'd say no, because $\infty$ is not a real number.